# How to set the facecolor in matplotlib axis while turning frame off?

Tags: matplotlib

I have found several ways to change the facecolor in my axes, but as soon as I attempt to also turn the frame off, the color disappears.

The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) suggest that this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.25,0.25,0.5,0.5], frameon=False, axisbg='g')
plt.show()
```

With `frameon=True`, I get:

[image]

However, with `frameon=False`, I get:

[image]

Is there another way to get a colored background w/o the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what `frameon` is supposed to do, but I got the effect that I was looking for by using:

```
for side in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
```